# .htaccess not removing .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess isn't removing the .php extension that I have set. :/

I've tried everything, even messed with some stupid stuff.

My `mod_rewrite` is enabled and have checked numerous times I've also `AllowOverride All` in my Apache Config.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

My current configuration is:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    deny from all
</Files> 
<Files ~ "^(.*)\.(inc|inc\.php|tpl|log)$">
    deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### Apache Exploits ####
RewriteCond %{HTTP:range} !(^bytes=[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,4}$|^$)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1
RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range
# optional logging, uncomment and set path to log matches
# CustomLog /var/log/range-CVE-2011-3192.log common env=bad-range
RequestHeader unset Range

#### Common Exploits ####
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} SELECT(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} UNION(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} UPDATE(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `RewriteRule` directive below exploits conditions. Try these rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### Apache Exploits ####
RewriteCond %{HTTP:range} !(^bytes=[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,4}$|^$)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1
RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range
# optional logging, uncomment and set path to log matches
# CustomLog /var/log/range-CVE-2011-3192.log common env=bad-range
RequestHeader unset Range

#### Common Exploits ####
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} SELECT(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} UNION(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} UPDATE(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

## hide .php extension

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```